# Scala mocking the behaviour

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito, stub

When I mock the particular object method is executing the actual behavior. 
The expected output should be `10`since I mocked the `Calculate.add` and returning the result as `10`

```scala
trait Base {
    def add (parm1:Int, parm2:Int): Int
    def fetc ():Any
    def compute(): Any
}

object Calculate extends Base {

    def add(parm1:Int, parm2:Int):Int = {
        fetc()
        compute
    }

    def fetc ():Any = {
        // Making some api1 call

    }

    def compute ():Any = {
        // Making some api2 call

    }
}


object Engine {
    def execute():any{
     Calculate.add(10, 20)
    }
}


Test

class TestEngine extends MockFactory {
    it should "compute" in {
        val res1:Int = 10
        val calculate: Base = stub[Base]
        val data = (calculate.add _).when(10, 20).returns(res1);
        Engine.execute() // ExpectedOutput should be 10(res1),Since the I mocked the add method and returning the 10 value. Should not call the Calculate object fetch, compute behaviour.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though Calculate is mocked & add method has been stubbed, still the actual functionality of add will be executed, since in Engine.execute method Calculate object reference is used to access the add method also Calculate is itself an object, thus the actual code will be executed.

```
object Engine {
  def execute():any{
    Calculate.add(10, 20)
  }
}
```

Simple solution to mocked calculate in Engine.execute could be instead of using Calculate object passed a base variable as method parameter.

```
object Engine {
  def execute(base: Base): Int = {
    base.add(10, 20)
  }
}
class TestEngine extends MockFactory {
  it should "compute" in {
    val res1: Int = 10
    val calculate: Base = stub[Base]
    val data = (calculate.add _).when(10, 20).returns(res1);
    //mocked_calculate
    Engine.execute(mocked_calculate) 
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a kind of dependency injection concept right?. Passing the dependency module as an argument . Other than this do we any testing library to fake the function behaviour?

Comment: Yes exactly, passing the dependency module as an argument. There might be other options available however I am not aware of them, also passing the dependency is the most reliable & scale-able.